# Invoke specific approval process

Tags: apex, custom-button, approval-process

I am a bit new to salesforce. Working with approval processes for the first time.

On case, i have 3 approval processes (AP1, AP2, AP3). Is there a way i can invoke a specific approval process.

One option i am considering -
Have a custom button for each approval process on the case page layout (Button1, Button2, Button3).
For Button1, i can write code to invoke AP1, and so on. I saw some code in developer guide.... i think i can work with that.

I wanted to know if there are other ways for me to do this. Especially if we have something out of the box for this. User should be able to decide which Approval process to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry of a record into Approval Process is determined by the entry criteria of the Approval Process.

If you want the user who submits the record for Approval process to determine which Approval process the record should be submitted, your approach of having 3 custom buttons will work. Only consideration is all the 3 Approval process should have same entry criteria.

If the record should get into any of 3 Approval process depending upon the values of fields in that record, you don't have to do anything custom. Just 3 Approval process with 3 different entry criteria will work.

Hope it helps you to understand better.

Comment: If all 3 processes have same entry criteria, what does clicking on "Submit for approval" button do? Does it send the case through all 3 approval processes (assuming entry criteria meets)? If so, in what order? Which approval process gets invoked first?

second scenario- there are 3 approval processes, each with different entry criteria. What happens behind the scenes when i click Submit for approval button? Does it checks entry criteria for all 3 processes? If so, in what order? If it meets the criteria of one approval process, will it still check for entry criteria of other approval processes

Comment: I guess i just want to understand what happens when you click "Submit for approval" button behind the scene, when there are multiple approval processes ... with and without same entry criteria

Comment: First it will check the entry criteria of the Approval processes. If a match found it stops searching and assign the record into that Approval process. This applies when you click submit for Approval button which is standard. The three Approval process with same criteria I suggested is for custom buttons which will assign the record to any of Approval process based on user selects which button

Answer (score 2):

You can use process builder. Out of the box and point and click.

[https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/business_process_automation/process_builder](http://Introduction%20to%20the%20Process%20Builder)